# How can I return multiple queries with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I am making a random website(own project for uni) that stores info about recent sports games and teams(team names and player names are made up) and I'd like to find out how can I(or what is the best way) to return player names that belong to their team.
Code example from .blade

```
    <details>
         <summary class="displayTeams"> Pueblo Thrashers </summary>
        <div class="allplayers">
        @foreach($PTh as $PTplayer)
            <p class="displayTeamsPlayer">{{$PTplayer->Name}} {{$PTplayer->LastName}} </p>
        @endforeach
        </div>
     </details>
<details>
 <summary class="displayTeams"> Raleigh Kings</summary>
    <div class="allplayers">
    @foreach($RKi as $RKplayer)    
    <p class="displayTeamsPlayer">{{$RKplayer->Name}} 
   {{$RKplayer>LastName}}</p>
    @endforeach  
    </div>
 </details>
```

Code example from my controller:

```
function showPlayers(){
    $PT = DB::table('players')->where('Team_ID', '1')->get();
    $RK = DB::table('players')->where('Team_ID', '2')->get();
return view('WHL', ['PTh' => $PT], ['RKi' => $RK]);
```

I have 6 more teams that I need to get players from, what's the best possible way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can user orWhere() in your Querie, like that :

```
 $PT = DB::table('players')->where('Team_ID', '1')->orWhere('Team_ID', '1')->orWhere('Team_ID', '3')->get(); return view('WHL', ['PTh' => $PT]);
```

Comment: Is one variable enough if I have 8 separate teams in my HTML code - how can I assign correct team_id values if I have @foreach?

Comment: I'm 100% sure this code will return wrong results.

Comment: @Ebo you can use whereIn() like that : $PT = DB::table('players')->whereIn('Team_ID', [1, 2, 3])->get();

Comment: @oussamazaqouri Yes, I get that but how can I assign these values to the correct teams if their names are "hard-coded" in the .blade.php page? The idea is that there's a page with all the teams that are in the selected league, when you click on a team there's a dropdown that displays all the players in that team (their name and last name).

Comment: @EBo With `->join()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `->whereIn()` like this:

```
function showPlayers(){
    $teams = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    $players = DB::table('players')->whereIn('Team_ID', $teams)->get();
    
   return view('WHL', ['players' => $players]);
}
```

And then in the blade file you can do the following

```
@foreach($players as $player)
    <details>
         <summary class="displayTeams"> Team {{ $loop->index }} </summary>
        <div class="allplayers">
            <p class="displayTeamsPlayer">{{$player->Name}} {{$player->LastName}} </p>
        </div>
     </details>
@endforeach
```